# Fill div with color when text exceed over certain hight, don't repeat CSS sprite bg image

Tags: css, background, background-image, sprite, stretch

A long title but hard to compress it without losing explanation.

Image explanation: http://img560.imageshack.us/f/skrmavbild20110321kl135.png/

So I have a div where text appears, the text could be different in how much it is. Attached to this div I have a background-image with a fading out effect. On the top grey then fading out to white. This image effect is fetched from a CSS sprite image.

My problem is when the text exceed over a certain height it makes the CSS sprite background image stretch so other image elements that is not supposed to show up shows up. This instead of showing the background color that is set.

How do I fix this?

Code:

```
.post-bg {
width: 572px;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
background: #fff url('images/sprite.png') no-repeat;
background-position: 0px -198px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Besides making a brand new image, this is probably the easiest fix:

Inside your sprite, move your "background-image with a fading out effect" image to the bottom of the image.

[***Live Demo***](http://jsfiddle.net/P9zcZ/)

Here's the test image I made to demonstrate:
[image]

You can see all the "other sprite images" are at the top of the file.

Comment: Ahh nice trick! But is'nt there a way to not be forced to move it to the bottom? If I move the images around in the CSS sprite file I have to change a lot of element background-positions.

Comment: No, I don't think there's a convenient way around this that doesn't involve making a new image. However, you only have to update the offset when you *change the height* of the sprite image. Consider making the sprite image `1000px` high or so to start off with. As it's a `.png`, the extra height won't make *any difference* to the file size. And it's fine to have a sprite with a large height, for instance, see the [Stack Overflow sprite image](http://sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/sprites.png?v=3) *(`1073px` high)*.